# How can an insecure image loaded via JS be removed/replaced safely?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, https, revolution-slider

I scanned the JS file for the link, but I can't find it.

An image with an insecure url of "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-IzPWLqY4gJ0/T01CPzNb1KI/AAAAAAAACgA/_8uyj68QhFE/s400/a2cf7051-5952-4b39-aca3-4481976cb242.jpg" was loaded via the javascript file: https://4ktee.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js?ver=5.4.3 on line 102.

I can share the line, but it's not very clean...

Comment: there is no image loading via that js file, might be from other

Comment: My apologies. It looks like the server ip is showing insecure. 

How does that even happen? The site loads via the domain name, but it's showing insecure. When I run a check it says that the ip address is returning.